# Tibco dataloss remote daemon did not satisfy our retransmission request

Tags: daemon, tibco, data-loss

I am having some real problems now with TIBCO RV, at the exact same time two machines reported dataloss on INBOUND. The 3rd machine, the remote daemon, did not report any unusual errors. This is happening too often, even though I've manually changed the rx/tx buffer size on network cards. I am not using CDM. Any ideas? Thanks

Machine 1
2013-01-08 12:58:21 /usr/tibco/tibrv/bin/realrvd64: TIB/Rendezvous Error: {ADV_CLASS="ERROR" ADV_SOURCE="SYSTEM" ADV_NAME="DATALOSS.INBOUND.BCAST" ADV_DESC="dataloss: remote daemon did not satisfy our retransmission request(s)" host="Machine 3" lost=3 scid=13001}

Machine 2
2013-01-08 12:58:21 /usr/tibco/tibrv/bin/realrvd64: TIB/Rendezvous Error: {ADV_CLASS="ERROR" ADV_SOURCE="SYSTEM" ADV_NAME="DATALOSS.INBOUND.BCAST" ADV_DESC="dataloss: remote daemon did not satisfy our retransmission request(s)" host="Machine 3" lost=3 scid=13001}

Comment: Do you have any RVRDs configured?

Comment: @TomHoward Hi Tom, between these machines there is no RVRD configured, they are in the same network. We've exhausted all the possible causes CPU load, network delays (even increased the UDP buffer, created a new dedicated broadcast interface) and the problem still persists. Even in a case where the remote daemon did resent the messages, there are cases when these messages are reported as lost again.

Comment: Hi CristiL, sorry I should have been more specific. Are there any RVRDs in the same subnet as these machines, with a local network defined using the same network and service settings as the clients that are getting the dataloss?

Comment: @TomHoward Hi Tom, no there arent any RVRDs in that network. I believe  we might have found the culprit, the FWSM might have problem with routing multicast generating RV losses

Comment: What network setting are you using for the transport?